# How to use the Contrast package in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set to which I am attempting to fit a single, fixed factor Anova model.

[image]

I was trying to use the contrast function from the contrast package to get a contrast for mu_1+mu_3=mu_2+mu4. 
Here is the fitted model I have so far with the contrast function I tried using

```
fit4=lm(weight~pop)
contrast(fit4, list(pop=as.factor(c(1:3)),list(pop=as.factor(c(2:4)))))
```

But I end up with more then one output, which is not what I am supposed to get. I think it's doing two separate contrasts rather then a single one.

lm model parameter contrast

```
  Contrast     S.E.    Lower    Upper     t df Pr(>|t|)
   2606.20 116.2542 2358.410 2853.990 22.42 15        0
   2506.75 129.9762 2229.712 2783.788 19.29 15        0
```

Comment: Learn to cut and paste text. Image files are completely, absolutely, irredeemably useless. Also do some self-study on how to format question-text so it displays properly in SO.